# Why can't I run IPython magic %%time and for loops?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, ipython, indentation

I'm trying to run a very simply loop and use the IPython magic `%%time`. However, I keep getting indentation errors when I run the loop with the magic. Note that I did import `random` before the following piece of code.

Input:

```
%%time
y = 0
for i in range(100):
    x = random.uniform(0, 1)
    y += x**2
```

Output:

```
File "<unknown>", line 3
x = random.uniform(0, 1)
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I tried making sure I'm using spaces. I also tried switching spaces to tabs but nothing seem to fix the issue.

The weird thing is that if I run the loop without the `%%time` magic, everything works fine and PyCharm doesn't return an indentation error. Similarly if I run the `%%magic` without the loop, IPython seem to work correctly.

Input:

```
%%time
y = 0
```

Output:

```
Wall time: 0 ns
```

It thus looks like the error stems from the interaction of IPython and the loop. Being fairly new to Python I wonder if anybody knows what is going on here?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your example works fine for me.

Comment: Check that you don't mix tab and spaces if/when you copy/past.